# Can java String.format handle replacing ? instead of %s

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table SELECT NULL WHERE '1'=?;",new String[]{"1"});
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO robot_active_variables\n" +
                    "SELECT NULL, ravs._id,str,val\n" +
                    "FROM ( SELECT 'is_answer' AS str, ? AS val\n" +
                    "UNION ALL SELECT 'is_setting', ?\n" +
                    "UNION ALL SELECT 'is_val', ?\n" +
                    "UNION ALL SELECT 'is_group_actions', ?\n" +
                    "UNION ALL SELECT 'is_lone_action', ?\n" +
                    "UNION ALL SELECT '_id', ?\n" +
                    "UNION ALL SELECT 'val', ? ) v\n" +
                    "join robot_active_variables_super ravs on ravs._id not in (select _id_parent from robot_active_variables);",new String[]{"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", String.valueOf(idAnswer), "0"})
```

And I want to use log.v to output the sql inserts.

1 What's it called to replace %s with String array, and what's the name for replacing '?' with String array? I noticed this strategy very often in c but never knew what's it called or how to google it.

2 Can formatter or any other method do the above replacements directly?

What i tried:

```
v1: Log.v("custom log.v call " , sql + bindArgs));
but i had to copy paste every var into the "?"

v2: Log.v("custom log.v call " , String.format(sql.replaceAll("\\?","%s"),bindArgs));
but then some queries didn't work, it seems that numbers are converted to text, ie: 'select 1=?' with new String[]{"1"} will give false because it becomes 'select 1="1"'

v3: Log.v("custom log.v call " , String.format(sql.replaceAll("\\?","\"%s\""),bindArgs));
works quite well
```

Comment: I do not know of anything in the Java or Android APIs that will do this. You will probably need to write your own search and replace algorithm. Note that after doing a search and replace, you do not have to use the resulting string for the query. In fact, you should still use the original string with the `?`s.

Comment: Why don't you just log the SQL and the value arrays, as they are? E.g. `sql + " " + Arrays.toString(bindArgs)`. That way you're logging what you actually do, e.g. if your code is bad and the number of `?` is wrong, you'd log what you do, rather than getting a different exception from the log statement saying that `%s` is unmatched.

Comment: Well I was using sqlliteman to run everything in there, because the compilation times are aweful in android studio. Also all the db errors in studio are terrible when compared to using a sqlliteman errors (and also you can see what tables contain what values)

Answer (score 1):

```
v2: Log.v("custom log.v call " , String.format(sql.replaceAll("\\?","%s"),bindArgs));
```

> but then some queries didn't work, it seems that numbers are converted to text, ie: 'select 1=?' with new String[]{"1"} will give false because it becomes 'select 1="1"'

```
v3: Log.v("custom log.v call " , String.format(sql.replaceAll("\\?","\"%s\""),bindArgs));
```

> works quite well

Either of these solutions is fine. Note that in the first version, you should still use the original string when executing the query, not the formatted one. As you noted, the formatted version of your query will convert all types to a String. This will allow the SQL engine to use the correct types and correct quoting to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: :D yes i am running both db.execSQL and Log.v commands and  db.execSQL does not use the formatter, only the Log.v